# R Shiny Dygraph pipe issue

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

This issue comes when I add more information to the dygraph element.

When I make a graph with dygraph like this:

```
 dygraph(timeseries1(),main="Test")
```

I haven't any problem but when I add the pipe or %>% with another instruction, I don't see anything. Indeed, the magrittr package is installed.

This is the code that doesn't run:

```
dygraph(timeseries1(),main="Test") %>%
dyOptions(axisLineColor="navy")
```

`sessionInfo()` output:

```
attached base packages: 
stats 
graphics 
grDevices 
utils 
datasets 
methods 
base 

other attached packages: 
htmlwidgets_0.5 
maptools_0.8-36 
scidb_1.1-2 
dygraphs_0.4.6 
shinythemes_1.0.1 
shinyjs_0.0.8.3 
magrittr_1.5 
shiny_0.12.1 
sp_1.1-1
```

Comment: Works for me, can you run `sessionInfo()` and post it, as well as a few lines of `timeseries1`?

Comment: I don't use sessionInfo(). Nevertheless I test the recommended example (https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/shiny.html) and I have the same mistake. When there is only the dygraph(), it is running, with more options not.

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't use `sessionInfo()`" ? it is not a drug you can take it with no risks.

Comment: This is the information that I obtained with sessionInfo():attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] htmlwidgets_0.5   maptools_0.8-36   scidb_1.1-2       dygraphs_0.4.6   
[5] shinythemes_1.0.1 shinyjs_0.0.8.3   magrittr_1.5      shiny_0.12.1     
[9] sp_1.1-1